# Linq query simplified

Tags: c#, linq

i have tried to manipulate some data using linq query. but i'm not sure the way i did was the best approach.

```
var makes = (from m in
            (from pv in vehicleViews
            let make = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri("http://www.someurl.com" + pv.Url).Query).Get("Criteria.Make")
            select new
            {
                Name = make,
                Y = pv.TotalViews,
            })
        group m by m.Name into g
        let total = g.Sum(x => x.Y)
        select new
        {
            Name = g.Key,
            Y = total
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Y);
```

is there anyway to simplified this query ?

Thanks

Comment: what does your query do? Describe your data source.

Comment: Why do you need to "simplify" it? Does it not work?

Comment: The linq code looks fine.  One question though, why is it going externally for make but internally for verhicleviews?  That's intersesting...

Comment: @John Peters vehicleViews data has the most viewed vehicle makes :)

Comment: Im not overly familiar with query syntax for LINQ, but i'm pretty sure that your lets are redundant and you can instead just assign the values straight in the object instantiation. i.e. Y = g.Sum(x => x.Y).

Comment: It would probably be more deficient to call `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri("http://www.someurl.com" + pv.Url).Query).Get("Criteria.Make")` on your grouped data, then you would only need to call it once per group rather than once per `vehicleViews`.

Comment: @BenRobinson Two different values of `pv.Url` might have the same `Criteria.Make`.

Comment: @Rawling yeah thats true!!

Comment: repost on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have a couple of excess projections, an unnecessary nested select before the grouping, and a use of method syntax that isn't strictly necessary. I beleive the following is equivalent to your query:

```
from pv in vehicleViews
let make = HttpUtility
    .ParseQueryString(new Uri("http://www.someurl.com" + pv.Url).Query)
    .Get("Criteria.Make")
group pv by make into g
let total = g.Sum(pv => pv.TotalViews)
orderby total descending
select new { Name = g.Key, Y = total };
```

The `let make =` line isn't strictly necessary (you could just `group by` that value directly) but it does make it clearer what you are calculating.